# Is Apache Thrift able to simply encode and decode data within JavaScript or other languages?

Tags: javascript, websocket, thrift

I am interested in two specific use cases.

1) C++ server communicating back and forth with an in-browser javascript client over WebSockets.
2) two in-browser javascript clients communicating over WebSockets to each other.

Ignoring complexities of C++ server in example 1, can Thrift be simply used for encoding/decoding of data streams rather than a all-in-one package that will handle communication channels?

Also is there any major advantage to using Thrift as the transport mechanism as well?

thanks